# Receiving Undefined Information from web service

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, jsonp

Here is the Code for my WebService,

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://mydomain.com/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class VBRService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string callJson(string x)
    {
        return "Worked =" + x;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void callJson2(string x, string callback)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(callback + "(");

        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize("aString");

        sb.Append(json);
        sb.Append(");");

        Context.Response.Clear();
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        Context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
        Context.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Here is the JavaScript Code,

```
$.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "http://localhost:31310/VBRService.asmx/callJson2",
        data: { x:"someDataPassed", callback:onDataReceived },
        dataType: "jsonp",
        error: function (data){
            alert(data.d);
        }
    });

    function onDataReceived(data) {
        alert(data.d);
        //       ^ Here is where the data comes back as undefined.
    }
```

The JavaScript fires off and hits the onDataReceived function. I'm not really sure as to if this is how you respond from a webService to perform a callback as there are not any examples of server side code to call to.

However, the object data is undefined when it calls back. This is cross domain by the way so that's why I'm trying to figure out how to use jsonp.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You (and us) need to know what the format of the returned json is to have any hope of getting anything out of it. `console.log(data)`

Comment: Also, i'm pretty sure your error callback is happening, and the xhr doesn't have a `d` property.

Comment: Even more, jsonp requests can't have a contentType defined and will ignore the crossDomain true parameter, and typically won't even execute the error callback.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to send a jsonp request. You're overcomplicating it.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:31310/VBRService.asmx/callJson2?callback=?",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {x: "somedata"},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Alternative:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:31310/VBRService.asmx/callJson2?callback=?",{x: "somedata"},function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: So do I have to change anything in my webservice to account for this? Sorry, just started using json today. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know, i'm not familiar with whatever server language you're using. It looks like you're just trying to send a string as json, typically json represents an array or structure, not just a simple string.